# spring-boot JWT OAuth2 AnonymousAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

In my spring-boot Application I try to use OAuth2 with JWT. 
But when I log in, I get only AnonymousAuthenticationToken and not the authenticated user.

That is my OAuth2 Configuration

```
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";


@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter getTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    // for asymmetric signing/verification use tokenConverter.setKeyPair(...);
    tokenConverter.setSigningKey("aTokenSigningKey");
    tokenConverter.setVerifierKey("aTokenSigningKey");
    return tokenConverter;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public JwtTokenStore getTokenStore(JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter) {
    return new JwtTokenStore(tokenConverter);
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");


        // @formatter:on
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenStore tokenStore;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .tokenEnhancer(this.tokenConverter)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("aClient")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("USER")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .secret("aSecret");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(this.tokenConverter);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
}
```

That is my WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable();
}


@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

That is my code for Login:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User aUser = UserRepository.fakeUserRepository.get(auth.getName());
```

But auth is AnonymousAuthenticationToken even if I give correct credentials.
Can somebody tell me what is missing?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have similar issue